# Create a 20px left padding when this function loops

Tags: php, css, loops

How can I format this code block so that every time this loop happens, 
it moves each hyperlink element 20px from the left?

It's working at the moment but for the whole div not single items.

Example: 
- LINK 1
-- LINK 2 
--- LINK 3

Any help would be appreciated!

```
$linkArray = array();
    $thisDir = '';
    $baseDir = ($htmlRoot == '') ? '' : $htmlRoot;
    for ($n=0; $n<count($dirArray); $n++) {
        $thisDir .= $dirArray[$n].'/';
        $thisIndex = MPBCDirIndex($htmlRoot.$thisDir);
        $thisText = ($n == 0) ? $topLevelName : MPBCFixNames($dirArray[$n]);
        $thisLink = ($thisIndex != '') ? '<span style="padding-left:20px;"><a href="'.$thisDir.$thisIndex.'">'.$thisText.'</a></span>' : $thisText;
        if ($thisLink != '') $linkArray[] = $thisLink;
        }

    $results = (count($linkArray) > 0) ? implode($separator, $linkArray) : '';
```

Comment: You have the padding-left property hard coded at 20px.  You need to use a variable if you want it to be ($n * 20).

Comment: what not use a list <ul><li> and style it?

Comment: Thanks for replying guys! Dagon, how would I implement a list in here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well hmmm.  You are already counting your iterations with the $n variable.  SO:

EG.

```
  for ($n=0; $n<count($dirArray); $n++) {

    $pxvar = $n * 20;

    $thisDir .= $dirArray[$n].'/';
    $thisIndex = MPBCDirIndex($htmlRoot.$thisDir);
    $thisText = ($n == 0) ? $topLevelName : MPBCFixNames($dirArray[$n]);
    $thisLink = ($thisIndex != '') ? '<span style="padding-left:'.$pxvar.'px;"><a href="'.$thisDir.$thisIndex.'">'.$thisText.'</a></span>' : $thisText;
    if ($thisLink != '') $linkArray[] = $thisLink;


    }
```

Note: the first iteration will have a padding of 0px.  Not sure if thats how you want it?

Comment: Thanks Ben, will also give this a try and let you know!

Comment: Worked perfectly with me Ben, thanks for helping out with this.